# SQL*Plus history under Linux

Tags: linux, history, sqlplus

How to make **sqlplus** in Linux to maintain history of my queries? So that I could use up/down arrows to get my previous query.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**rlwrap** package is needed. Used like this:

`$ rlwrap sqlplus user/password@sid`

Nice to place alias to .bashrc:

```
alias sqlplus="rlwrap sqlplus"
```

Found answer here:

[http://sysdba.wordpress.com/2006/10/08/how-to-use-rlwrap-to-get-a-command-history-in-sqlplus/](http://sysdba.wordpress.com/2006/10/08/how-to-use-rlwrap-to-get-a-command-history-in-sqlplus)

Comment: Use "rlwrap -l" to make rlwrap accept CTRL-C to cancel running commands.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the release "Oracle 12c release 2" (SQL*Plus Release 12.2.0.1.0) they have now introduced the history command.

For the up / down arrows you probably still need rlwrap though.

Reference for history command:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/SQPUG/HISTORY.htm#SQPUG-GUID-CCF9B047-3122-4644-BA06-5FA4B5812E9F